# background-position is not working properly

Tags: html, css, sass, jekyll

I am using Jekyll and I have the following code where I change the inline `background-position` depending on the front-matter `position` that I define:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.page__hero--overlay {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  padding: 3em 0;
  clear: both;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  -webkit-animation: intro 0.3s both;
  animation: intro 0.3s both;
    animation-delay: 0s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.25s;
  animation-delay: 0.25s;
}

@media (min-width: 80em)
.page__hero--overlay .wrapper {
  max-width: 1280px;
}

.page__hero--overlay .wrapper {
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
}

.wrapper {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.page__hero--overlay .wrapper {
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
}

.parallax {
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.page__hero--overlay .page__title {
  font-size: 1.953em;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.page__title {
  margin-top: 0;
  line-height: 1;
}

h1, h2 {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
  font-size: 1.563em;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  margin: 2em 0 0.5em;
    margin-top: 2em;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-family: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Roboto","Segoe UI","Helvetica Neue","Lucida Grande",Arial,sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

p {
  margin-bottom: 1.3em;
}

.page__hero--overlay .page__lead {
  max-width: 768px;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.page__lead {
  font-family: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Roboto","Segoe UI","Helvetica Neue","Lucida Grande",Arial,sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.25em;
}
```

```html
<div class="page__hero--overlay parallax" style=" background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1514496959998-c01c40915c5f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1740&q=80'); background-position: 25% 90%;">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h1 id="page-title" class="page__title" itemprop="headline">Title</h1>  
    <div style="margin-top: 130px;"></div>
    <p class="page__lead">Something<br>Something</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

However when on desktop (w:1500px h:600+) I can't "pull the image up" without having `background-position: 25% 1000%;` and on mobile (w:<500- h:900) it has absolutely no effect whatsoever and I don't understand why.

`Calc(100% - 200px)` kind of works on small screens but it completely breaks (how I want the image) on larger screens. What am I doing wrong?

I am mostly looking for an inline fix because of Jekyll (AFAIK I can't pass variables to SASS)

Comment: Why not just remove `background-position: fixed`?

Comment: @ralph.m Because I want the parallax effect that comes with it

Comment: But `fixed` won't play with `cover`, because they do different things.

Comment: I noticed that if I take `cover` the image gets insanely zoomed in (huge)

Comment: Yes, the image is very large by default, and `cover` helps fit it into the container. Maybe compromise with `fixed` and `cover` but leave off `background-position`.

Answer (score 0):

```
.page__hero--overlay {
background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1514496959998-c01c40915c5f');
    width: 100%;
    height: 60vh;
    max-height: 650px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
```

Set this css in your style code so that your responsive can be set to automatic and also create a media query and set the max-height as you wish.

I hope it works for you. And if it doesn't work for my bad.
thank you.